# Run content script in scope of a single tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension for Google Chrome. I have created an icon for my extension. What I'd like to do, is the following:

1. A user clicks extension's icon.
2. A new tab is opened.
3. Content scripts are run as set in manifest file, but only in this
   tab.

I think it's clear, but e.g.: let's say I set in my manifest file a following property:

```
"content_scripts" : [
    {
        "matches" : ["http://stackoverflow.com"],
        "js" : ["script.js"]
    }
]
```

And let's say I have 2 tabs: the first one was opened manually, and the second one was opened by clicking extension's icon. Now, I open the stackoverflow's index page in both tabs. In the first tab nothing happens, but in the second one the "script.js" script is run.
How can I achieve it? I know I can implement a tab's id checking, but isn't there any simpler way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `content_scripts` entry in the manifest in this case. You can use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` calls to run the content scripts. You will need to track which tabs you created but that's not hard.

You can have something like this in a background script:

```
var createdTabs = {};

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  chrome.tabs.create( {}, function( tab ) {
     createdTabs[tab.id] = true;
  }
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdate.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
  if( createdTabs[tabId] && changeInfo.url )
    chrome.tabs.executeScript( tabId, {file: 'script.js'} );
}
```